# what is the best way to send info back to user

Tags: php

i have a form element on my page like this:

```
<form id="form1" action="email.php" method="post">
//some input textbox and a submit button
</form>
```

form send  info to email.php in another file. and after email is sent i want to show a success message to the user. what is the best way to show success message to user. using cookie maybe the user browser disable. if i using session. it's take huge RAM space when for example 10000 user want to send email. URL is not secure>>.... what is the best way. in addition i don't want to use ajax

Comment: SESSION is the best way to show the message..

Comment: If you want something nice for user you could use some jquery like $.post to a php file and then retrieve whatever the result is and customize it using JQuery to make it eye-catching

Comment: I don't see why redirecting to `page.php?success=1` or similar is unsafe...

Comment: because users can easily change it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my opinion:

**Session** >>

All data that you ar storing in session will be stored on the server. The default location is disk. IO - is a very limited resource. Do not start sessions when you do not need to. Do not store data in sessions when you do not need to.

**If you have many PHP scripts that use session variables, consider recompiling PHP using the shared memory module for sessions, or use a RAM Disk. Enable this with "configure -–with-mm" then re-compile PHP, and set session.save_handler=mm in php.ini.**

**Supply the new page with some GET parameters.**>>

It is a good practice, but has one lack. If the client stores links in his favorites (and etc...) gives it to another user and he opens this link later, then he will see the success message.

**Supply more than the Location header and read them on the target page.**>>

It is a good method, but it depends on the server configuration and proxies in the middle of application and client. Sometimes the server configuration (proxies) kill non standard headers. But usually it is not a problem.

**Store this data in cookies.**>>

Lacks:

Do not forget to delete cookies.
All data stored in cookies will be transferred from your server to client and back.
Store this data on the server.

**Storing in database**>>, memcache, NoSQL and etc. If this does not create additional load on the server and is ideally suited for your application, why not? And you need not necessarily to store the message itself, but only a state flag.

In practice I use all this methods. Which method should be used at the moment - look at the requirements for the application and its future use.